# how to add last login date in application using nodejs and mongodb?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to add last login date in my application.But I can't able to achieve it.The current date and last login date are same in my code....please some one help me......[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyeYV.png)
[

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const schema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },

    email:{
        type:String,
        unique:true,
        required:true
    },

    hash: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    defaultAccountId:{
        type:Number,
        required:true

    },
    buisnessUnit:{
        type:Array,
        required:true

    },
    
    createdDate: {
        type: Date,
       default: Date.now
    },
    lastLoginDate: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
schema.statics.login = function login(id, callback) {
    return this.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { $set : { 'lastLoginDate' : Date.now() },  new : true }, callback);
 };
schema.set('toJSON', {
    virtuals: true
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', schema);
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyeYV.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your part of code to this and you are done.

```
schema.statics.login = function login(id, callback) {
    return this.findByIdAndUpdate(id,{'$set' : { 'lastLoginDate' : Date.now()} }, { new : true }, callback);
 };
```