# Keep track of last login date with NodeJS and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on adding a last login functionality to my Node app and can't seem to get it to work.  Here's what I've got for a mongoose `user` schema:

```
userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    password: String,
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true 
    },
    avatar: String,
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    lastLogin: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    resetPasswordToken: String,
    resetPasswordExpires: Date,
    isAdmin: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    }
});


userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

userSchema.statics.newLogin = function login(id, callback) {
    return this.findByIdAndUpdate(id,{'$set' : { 'lastLogin' : Date.now()} }, { new : true }, callback);
 };


module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

Here's my login route:

```
router.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", 
    {
        failureRedirect: "/login"
    }), function(req, res) {
    User.findOneAndUpdate(req.username, {lastLogin: Date.now()}, (err, data) => {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    else console.log("Successfully updated the lastLogin", data);

    res.redirect("/players");
  });
});
```

I've been able to get the initial date to stick when the account is created; however, when I login with that same account the date remains unchanged.  What am I missing here?

There are a few other questions with similar topics, but none seem to resolve my issue.  Specifically, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59859512/how-to-add-last-login-date-in-application-using-nodejs-and-mongodb) question where I've implemented part of the solution to no avail.  Thanks in advance for the help!

Here's the code currently being tested, example req.body:

```
{ username: 'anyUserHere', password: 'anyPasswordHere' }
```

req.user:

```
{
  isAdmin: true,
  _id: 5e9b301a6bb78973c9ec8fae,
  username: 'anyUserHere',
  salt: 'saltValue',
  hash: 'hashValue',
  __v: 0,
  avatar: '../images/admin.jpg',
  email: 'example@example.com',
  firstName: 'first',
  lastName: 'last',
  password: 'anyPasswordHere',
  lastLogin: 2020-05-22T18:35:50.941Z
}
```

So in this case, the 'anyUserHere' example should be the one being updated, but the update occurs to the first user in Mongo.  Console output:

```
Successfully updated the lastLogin {
  isAdmin: false,
  _id: 5e939f988ced3e0428c8b521,
  username: 'test',
  __v: 0,
  lastLogin: 2020-05-22T18:38:59.836Z
}
```

Comment: Where are  you making the call to the `login` method in your code

Comment: @Vishnu - I've updated my code to show something I've tried that does not change the lastLogin value successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you update the `User.newLogin();` with the below code and try

```js
  User.newLogin(id, (err, data) => {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    else console.log("Successfully updated the lastLogin", data);
  });
```

```js
router.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", 
    {
        failureRedirect: "/login"
    }), function(req, res) {

    User.newLogin(id, (err, data) => {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    else console.log("Successfully updated the lastLogin", data);

    res.redirect("/players");
  });
});
```

Edit

According to the current approach with `findOneAndUpdate` you need to make the following updated to the `filter`

```js
   User.findOneAndUpdate({username: req.username}, {lastLogin: Date.now()}, (err, data) => {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    else console.log("Successfully updated the lastLogin", data);

    res.redirect("/players");
  });
```

Comment: I've added this to the post just to ensure we're o the same page.  Unfortunately, I'm not getting any output to the console and the lastLogin value remains the same.

Comment: Are you getting any other error in the console?. Since we are logging both error and success response

Comment: Nothing gets output to the console, which leads me to believe that the code is not even being run after a login success.

Comment: Alright, so we're making progress here.  The lastLogin value is getting updated, but for the same "test" user each time regardless of who is actually logging in.  Posting the updated code above.

Comment: Can you update `User.findOneAndUpdate(req.username, {lastLogin: Date.now()}..` this to `User.findOneAndUpdate({username : req.username}, {lastLogin: Date.now()}..` and try. If no records matched it will take the first record and thats why first record got updated

Comment: Alright, that was fantastic information.  With that change and updating to: {username: req.user.username} did the trick it seems.  Update your answer with this and I'll mark it at resolved.  Thanks!

Comment: @Franchise Good to know its working. I have updated the answer